# What are some known hazards with cyclical replication between two MySQL master servers?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.6, replication

If I were to set up cyclical replication between a MySQL 5.6 master server and a MySQL 5.1 master server, what are some things that could potentially go wrong?

Also, the 5.6 MySQL does not have GTID enabled.

Thanks IS

Answer (score 2):

Cringe, gag, etc.

5.1 and 5.6 differ by *2* *major* versions.  Replication is 'guaranteed' to work one direction, not the other.

Don't turn on GTIDs in 5.6; 5.1 will not like it.

Don't use any features new to 5.5 or 5.6.

Simply, don't do it.  Get the 5.1 upgraded ASAP.

Comment: Agreed.  Failure is very likely, in such an environment.  To put a fine point on it, this setup isn't guaranteed to work in *either* direction. [*"MySQL supports replication from one major version to the next higher major version."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-compatibility.html).  Specifically, that means *from* and older master and *to* a newer slave, only.  In circular replication, both servers have both roles, and a newer master with an older slave *"may be possible, but is generally not supported"*.  There are too many changes for backwards replication to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Replication from MySQL 5.x to 5.6 has a bear trap just waiting for you.

In [Michael's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99071/what-are-some-known-hazards-with-cyclical-replication-between-two-mysql-master-s#comment178873_99075), he stated the politically accept premise : "MySQL supports replication from one major version to the next higher major version.". He also said "this setup isn't guaranteed to work in either direction."

I have a very interesting caveat on going from 5.x to 5.6: There are some rare occasions when a binlog event from a pre-5.6 master cannot be interpreted by 5.6 slave and stops replication cold. I wrote about this in January (See my post [mysql replication master 5.5 slave 5.1 error on create database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87423/mysql-replication-master-5-5-slave-5-1-error-on-create-database/87438#87438))

[I concluded my old post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87423/mysql-replication-master-5-5-slave-5-1-error-on-create-database/87438#87438) with this

> If this crazy scenario was possible from a MySQL 5.5.30 Master to MySQL 5.6.21 Slave, (as I have shown happen and two maintenance cycles to correct), then the reverse is far more likely (the reverse being a new Master and an older Slave).

You do not want circular replication for 5.1/5.6. While you can replicate from 5.1 to 5.6, please don't stay long in that setup. The binlog format differences are very slight, but different enough to break replication. As [@RickJames said "Simply, don't do it. Get the 5.1 upgraded ASAP."](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99075/877)

While I could expound just on circular replication, I refer you to

- The Scale-Out Blog : [If You *Must* Deploy Multi-Master Replication, Read This First](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.com/2012/04/if-you-must-deploy-multi-master.html)
- Oracle : [Circular Replication in MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/circular_replication_in_mysql)